# How to save a dynamic name of input in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an input tag which is being parsed with id, within a form. I am trying to get  **`$data = $request->all();`**

I am trying to pluck the value and store the value being shown in [licensing-1-61]. The issue is that i am not sure on how to parse the id when saving the value:
[image: Image contains the value needed to be stored]

Blade:

```
 <input type="text" value="{{isset($two->answer->score) ? $two->answer->score : '' }}" name="licensing-{{ $one->id.'-'.$two->id }}" id="licensing-{{ $one->id.'-'.$two->id }}" style="min-width: 100px;" onblur="saveScore()"/>
```

Ajax Function:

```
 function saveScore() 
     {
        var datastring = $("#score-license").serialize();

         if(datastring != '')
          {
             $.ajaxSetup({
             headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                 }
             });

             $.ajax({
                 url:"{{route('staff.regulatory.licensing.storeScore',['id'=>$two->id])}}",
                 type: 'PUT',
                 data: datastring,
                 dataType : 'JSON',
                 success:function(data)
                 {   
                    console.log(data); 
                    alert("Success");  
                 },
                 error:function(message)
                 { 
                  //location.reload(); 
                  alert(JSON.stringify(message));
                 } 

             });

          }
     }
```

Controller:

```php
 public function storeScore(Request $request, $id)
 {
     //print_r($request->all());
     $data = $request->all();
     $selected = PreLicensingMain::where('id', $id)
                                     ->with('levelone.leveltwo')
                                     ->first();
     $selected->main_answer = PreLicensingMainAnswer::where('pre_licensing_main_id', $selected->id)->where('centre_id', $staff->centre_id)->first();
     foreach ($selected->levelone as $key => $one) {
         foreach ($one->leveltwo as $key => $two) {
             $two->answer = PreLicensingAnswer::where('pre_licensing_level_two_id', $two->id)->where('centre_id', $staff->centre_id)->first();     
         }
     }

     foreach ($data["licensing-{{ $one->id.'-'.$two->id }}"] as $group) {
         if (!is_null($group["licensing"])) {
             $licensingtask = new PreLicensingAnswer; 
             $licensingtask->score = $group["licensing"];
             $licensingtask->save(); 
         }
     }


 }
```

Comment: try to do dd($data) and update that response in your question

Comment: dd($data). returns me error message of 

{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\\[\\]\\/\\\\])/g, idRx = /\\bsf-dump-\\d+-ref[012]\\w+\\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild...........